# Why file loader is important?

Tags: javascript, webpack, file-loader

Why is it important to use a file loader while I can use the absolute path for my file? say image for example...

In this case, I want to use an image called `img.jpg` :

```
import myImage from "../assets/img.jpg"

    function addImage(src) {
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.alt = "our image";
        image.src = src;
        const body = document.querySelector("body")
        body.appendChild(image)
    }
    addImage(myImage)
```

This code wouldn't work without a file loader but if I use the path of the image, that would work...

```
addImage("./dist/kemo.jpg")
```

So, I ask here why the file loader is important if I can dispense of it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, file-loader is important because;

- It resolves `import` on a file into a `url` and emits the file into the output directory.
- Additionally, anything loaded with file-loader gets included in the assets JSON output of webpack, so you can see all the assets in one place

**Getting Started**

Begin by installing file-loader:

$ `npm install file-loader --save-dev`

then for you to import myImage from '../assets/img.jpg';

You will have to add the loader to your webpack config. For example:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And when you run webpack via your preferred method. This will emit img.jpg as a file in the output directory (with the specified naming convention, if options are specified to do so) and returns the public URI of the file.

> ℹ️ By default the filename of the resulting file is the hash of the
> file's contents with the original extension of the required resource.

Comment: Yeah, that's very helpful.